# Constructor for DateTimeIndex on Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create an empty dataframe with a DateTimeIndex. I'm going to populate the df iteratively from another routine. I can't seem to instantiate it properly with an index. What am I doing wrong?

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(
   columns=['Date', 'a','b','c'], 
   dtype=[datetime, float, float, float], 
   index='Date')
```

(current error here, `datetime` isn't recognised, but I'm looking to fix the constructor syntax as well, which I believe is wrong).

Thanks!

Comment: Try `my_df = pd.DataFrame(
   columns=['Date', 'a','b','c'], 
   dtype=[np.datetime64, float, float, float], 
   index=Date)`

Comment: Weirdly this produces: `TypeError: data type not understood`

Comment: have you already imported numpy? add `import numpy as np` prior to this line

Comment: Yes. Just for good measure I've restarted everything, weirdly it still doesn't recognise it (although np.datetime64 is defined).

Comment: I get the same error, why do you need to define the dtypes upfront anyway? And also why do you need an empty df? Normally when you assign a column the dtype will get set by the source dtype

Comment: You make a good point; I decided to copy it from another series and that seems to have done it. I'm not sure why using the constructor didn't work (it *should* have, right?), but at least I get on now ;). Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I'm not sure either but generally it's not necessary to declare an empty df and populate it, either pass the data as part of the ctor or assign the columns as required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['Date', 'a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=np.float)
my_df['Date'] = my_df['Date'].astype(np.datetime64)
my_df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```